# How to detect new element creation in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

Lets say I have the following code that returns number of anchor elements on a page:

```
function getLinkCount() {
    alert("Links:" + $("a").length);
}
```

If I call in on document ready it would work as expected. But what if now a new link gets inserted into a page dynamically through Javascript, how can I get notified to run link counter function again? (I have no control over a script that could create a new link).

Basically I am looking for something similar to `live()` only that would be watching element creation event, something like:

```
$("a").live("create", getLinkCount);
```

that would trigger when a new element is created.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the [`.livequery()` plugin](https://github.com/hazzik/livequery/blob/master/README.md) for this, it runs for each element, including new ones, like this:

```
$("a").livequery(getLinkCount);
```

However, this plugin is out-of-date and is not recommended for current versions of jQuery.

It's usually easier to do this when you create the elements though, for example if you're doing it after AJAX requests, the [`.ajaxComplete()` handler](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) may be a good place, for example:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(getLinkCount);
```

This would run after each request, and since you normally create elements in your `success` handler, they would already be present when this complete handler runs.

Comment: .livequery() plugin doesn't exists anymore. I'm searching for a new solution

Comment: @MarcoPanichi do you need to actually detect when an element is added, or you just want the events to work on everything?  In that case a delegate style `.on()` is what you're after.

Answer (score 43):

You could use the DOMSubtreeModified event.  For example:

```
$(document).bind('DOMSubtreeModified',function(){
  console.log("now there are " + $('a').length + " links on this page.");
})
```

Comment: Good idea. Probably I can use even `DOMNodeInserted` event that has an actual element that was inserted as a target, so I can check whether or not it was an anchor before running a method.

Comment: Right it doesn't work in IE , but it is the only way to be notified on DOM modifications by any means possible (non-jQuery).

All other solutions I found assume the modifications are done via jQuery functions or, worse, make  use of ugly setInterval(). In my specific case IE support is not required (yay!)

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [arrive.js](https://github.com/uzairfarooq/arrive/) library that I developed for the exact same purpose (it uses [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) internally). Usage:

```
document.arrive('a', function(){
    // 'this' refers to the newly created element
    var newElem = this;
});
```

Comment: This made my day! Happy that I stumble into this great plugin.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much Uzair! If you want to have new images do something once they're created and loaded, this is what you need. jQuery cannot do this. E.g. right at the top of your page: ```document.arrive("selector to your > img", function() { this.onload = function() { this.style.opacity = 1 }   }    )```

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer is from 2010 and uses a jQuery plugin that is no longer being actively maintained. The highest upvoted answer suggests using `DOMSubTreeModified` which [is now deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMSubtreeModified) and should no longer be used.

**Today, a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) is what you should use to detect when an element has been added to the DOM.** MutationObservers are now widely supported across all modern browsers (Chrome 26+, Firefox 14+, IE11, Edge, Opera 15+, etc).

Here's a simple example of how you can use a `MutationObserver` to listen for when an element is added to the DOM.

For brevity, I'm using jQuery syntax to build the node and insert it into the DOM.

```
var myElement = $("<div>hello world</div>")[0];

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
   if (document.contains(myElement)) {
        console.log("It's in the DOM!");
        observer.disconnect();
    }
});

observer.observe(document, {attributes: false, childList: true, characterData: false, subtree:true});

$("body").append(myElement); // console.log: It's in the DOM!
```

The `observer` event handler will trigger whenever any node is added or removed from the `document`. Inside the handler, we then perform a `contains` check to determine if `myElement` is now in the `document`.

You don't need to iterate over each MutationRecord stored in `mutations` because you can perform the `document.contains` check directly upon `myElement`.

To improve performance, replace `document` with the specific element that will contain `myElement` in the DOM.