# jQuery event when element is created

Tags: jquery

I'd like to trigger an event when an element is created.

```
$(document).on('load','#TB_title',function() {
    console.log('loaded');
});
```

Is there an equivalent of this that works?

I saw some people suggest livequery, but that seems heavy.

Thanks.

Comment: Note: #TB_title is not an iframe.

Comment: Please expand upon 'when an element is created'. Do you mean when an element is added to the DOM?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to trigger a function once a thickbox loads.

Comment: I don't think you're going to get away from using something "heavy".  Browsers don't fire an event when an element is added to the DOM so you will need something to determine that on the fly.  Otherwise you will need to write your code in such a way that you know when things are added and act accordingly.

Comment: @rpophessagr http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384398/how-to-detect-new-element-creation-in-jquery

Comment: does the thickbox load content from a different domain ?

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli no. same domain.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery on load of dynamic element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610267/jquery-on-load-of-dynamic-element)

Answer (score 6):

I don't think such thing exist directly, but you can handle the `DOMSubtreeModified` event and wait until you can find element with such ID:

```
var _elementToFind = "TB_title";
var _elementFound = false;
var _counter = 1;
$(document).bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function(evt) {
    if (_elementFound)
        return;
    if ($("#" + _elementToFind).length > 0) {
        alert("element '" + _elementToFind + "' created");
        _elementFound = true;
    }
});
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/keGxy/).

The downside is that it's not supported by Opera and IE less than 9 - [see here](http://help.dottoro.com/ljrmcldi.php) the full details.

Answer (score 3):

You can trigger a global custom event:

```
$(document).on('load','#TB_title',function() {
  $.event.trigger('nameOfCustomEvent');  
});

$('#element').bind('nameOfCustomEvent', function(){
  console.log(this);
});
```

Comment: The trigger will never fire, that's the problem OP is asking about.