# Anchor tag click events not working after displaying the data using ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

When I reload the page, I call ajax to get the data and display it on the screen.

```
<div class="empList"><ul></ul></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'process.php',
    method: 'post',
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      action: "employeelist"
    },
    success: function(data) {
      var trHTML = '';

      $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        trHTML += '<li><div class="employeeShareWrap"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="shareSocial" data-id="' + item.id + '">Share</a></div></li>';
      });
      $('.empList ul').append(trHTML);
    }
  })
});

//clicking on the share button 
$(".employeeShareWrap>a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('hi');
  alert("hello");
});
// this is the second way i tried
/*
   $(".employeeShareWrap>a").click(function(){
    var otherInput=$(this).data("id");  
    alert(otherInput);
    alert("hello");
   });*/
<script>
```

As of now, I am displaying the share button for testing purposes. Now My issue is when I am clicking on the share button then I am not getting any alert. There is no error in the console.

And if I added directly in the HTML then it's working.

```
<li><div class="employeeShareWrap"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="shareSocial" data-id="51">Share</a></div></li>
<script type="text/javascript">
        
$(".employeeShareWrap>a").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
console.log('hi');
alert("hellow");

});
    </script>
```

Is there any issue with my script or I am displaying it in a wrong way?

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610267/jquery-on-load-of-dynamic-element

Comment: [Understanding Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the reference link. I'll refer in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the anchor tag hasn't been created yet, by the time you try to attach your listener to it. Consider using the [`on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) method instead:

```
$(document).on('click', '.employeeShareWrap > a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('hi');
    alert("hellow");
});
```

Comment: Oh! Thanks for the information. Yes, It's working perfectly.  One more thing.I added the second way in the question. Is that the best way?

Comment: If your anchor tag is not dynamically being rendered with JS and it's static, then the second way is the recommended way.

Comment: Note there are several signatures of `on()` and this one uses  a delegation selector. `on()` alone does not necessarily solve the problem