# call function on element creation

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is there a way to call a function on a specific selector that would apply to any element that matches that selector now, and in the future?

Just the way it works (before it was deprecated) with live.

Something like:

```
$('form.validate').live('create', validate);
```

Comment: If I remember correctly - `on` (http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: create is an event or what?

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384398/how-to-detect-new-element-creation-in-jquery

Comment: There's nothing such as "onChange" or "onCreate" in jQuery, or Javascript. However, you can try [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-jquery-dom-change-listener/11546242#11546242).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a jQuery DOM change listener?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-jquery-dom-change-listener)

Comment: Yes Blazemonger. And it helped a lot. Just as PSR comment. Thak u guys.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Consider updating your answer with a brief summary of the relevant points (instead of just a link), so it is still meaningful to others if that link ever breaks.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of `live` in the current version is:

```
$('form').on('create', '.validate', validateFunction);
```

Now, since the `create` event is not a standard DOM event, it is you who fires it. You must have somewhere (for example when you render the form):

```
// ... create a .validate element
validateElement.trigger('create');
```

The `on` syntax above should catch this `create` event.