# Using jQuery .on() for load event with future DOM objects

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery which runs inside the document.ready event currently:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $("#featured-stores .inner").ultimateCarousel();
});
```

However, I need to apply this to future DOM elements as they are created. If this was something that happened on click then it would be fairly obvious how to use .on(), but I cannot see a way to run code that should normally run inside document.ready with the .on() function.

Is this because it's not possible, or am I missing something really simple? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect new element creation in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384398/how-to-detect-new-element-creation-in-jquery)

Comment: Try `$(document).on('load','#featured-stores .inner', function(){$(this).ultimateCarousel();});`